# Not been able to writeToFile iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using following code to download an slqite file and storing it

```
self.responseData = NSMutableData
```

I receive `responseData = 2048bytes`. working well.

However white writing it does create a file `myFile.sqlite` but it is of Zero bytes.
What is wrong?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        if(self.responseData)
        {
            dbPath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.selectedBtn.dbPath lastPathComponent]];
            [self.responseData writeToFile:dbPath atomically:YES];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"list" sender:self];
        }
    }

    [self.alertView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(NSString *) getDBPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.selectedBtn.dbPath lastPathComponent]];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
}
```

I am getting error

```
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)`

dbPath : /Users/umar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/00027635-CE9C-48C3-8000-64CA1E6532F1/Documents/music.sqlite/music.sqlite
```

Comment: The `writeToFile` returns a `BOOL`, so its worth checking the return value. Also consider `-(BOOL)writeToFile:options:error:`. Investigating the error object may give some clues as well.

Comment: Also, are you certain `getDBPath` returns a valid path?

Comment: Path is valid, @MikeD yes i am already trying error, give me a second :)

Comment: @MikeD please check the edited code with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending `[self.selectedBtn.dbPath lastPathComponent]` twice, once in `getDBPath`, and again ion `connctionDidFinishLoading`.

Pick one of those instances to remove.

Answer (score 1):

```
Documents/music.sqlite/music.sqlite
```

Nah, this is not a valid path... You meant `Documents/music.sqlite`, didn't you? Also, I don't see why you're raping poor `NSURL` for an unrelated task.

```
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.selectedBtn.dbPath lastPathComponent]];
```

Also, make sure `self.selectedBtn.dbPath` also is indeed a valid path and not junk (I could imagine it is).